# Hover over an image area to change the image src

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Basically, I have an image (of text) that I want to change to one of four other images on rollover of different areas. The difference is, on roll-off, I want it to remain what it was changed to, unless my mouse enters a different area. I've tried image-maps and whatnot but I can't seem to get this right. As far as my overall coding knowledge goes... well, I started last week, but I'm getting there.

[Here's a link to an image overview of what i (kind of) mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To2ta.jpg)

I know it has probably been answered somewhere at some point but I really haven't managed to find anything that works yet - all I've managed is stuff that either disappears completely or doesn't work with multiple images. Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Comment: Your going to have to use javascript to change the image on hover of the image map area's. you shouldnt have to handle the 'off hover' (badly worded im sorry) as you want the images to remain. Might wanna pre load the images if they are on the large side

Comment: @DAVIEAC Right, awesome. I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to javascript but that's what Google is for, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use image maps

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

this is great tool, try it. it is not so hard :)

Comment: I gave the image mapper linked from that site a go, but it seems like the site wasn't working. I'm not 100% sure how to use the jQuery thing I've downloaded from there but I will do some Googling and see what I can come up with. Thanks.